# Using meta attribute inside a downloader middleware

Tags: python, scrapy, recaptcha

According to the Scrapy docs, one cannot use `response.request` in a downloader middleware because request object will be attached to response only after passing all other downloader middlewares. Though I have noticed that in case of redirect (to captcha page), responses inside a downloader middleware have not only empty `request` field - but also empty meta (pycharm debugger tells me that the response is not related with any request). How could I force Scrapy to keep the meta while processing inside a downloader middleware? I have placed `meta=response.meta` to every request but still getting errors about missing meta keys - and absent meta attribute aswell.

```
    def start_requests(self):

        for value in values::
            yield Request(
                self.SEARCH_URL,
                                ),
                meta={'ssomekey': value},
            )
```

From downloaders middleware:

```
    def process_response(self, request, response, spider):

        if not hasattr(response, 'meta'):
            print "there is no meta"
```

After launching immediately prints "there is no meta"

Comment: Where does it say that? I check documentation and there is no such reference? https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#activating-a-downloader-middleware, you should be using `process_response`. Also post the code that you have tried?

Comment: I think there is such reference: [link](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html) in Response.request section: _This attribute is assigned in the Scrapy engine, after the response and the request have passed through all Downloader Middlewares. In particular, this means that:
...
This attribute is only available in the spider code, and in the Spider Middlewares, but not in Downloader Middlewares (although you have the Request available there by other means) and handlers of the response_downloaded signal._

Comment: On the other hand, from `meta` section on the same page: _Unlike the Response.request attribute, the Response.meta attribute is propagated along redirects and retries, so you will get the original Request.meta sent from your spider._ - so Im wondering why `meta` hasnt been copied in some cases

Comment: See this SO post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20805932/scrapy-retry-or-redirect-middleware

Comment: Thanks, though I dont see how it could help. I have added handle_httpstatus_list to my spider, but 405 responses with captcha page have no meta despite of the fact it has been added to requests

Comment: What about using `request.meta` in `process_response`? It is after all the meta you set for the request that got this response.

Comment: Unfortunately, like I said, some responses when you look at them from downloader middleware, have None request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The request object is available as an argument to the `process_response` method of downloader middlewares, not just `process_request`.  Like @paul-trmrth suggests, instead of `response.meta` or `response.request.meta`, use `request.meta`, and this is propagated through all middlewares on both ends of download and through to the spider.

https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.DownloaderMiddleware.process_response

Sorry to necro, but I had the same question and found an answer.